# Where can I find Mac OS Software Glossaries?

Tags: macos

A few years ago, Apple released software glossaries (bilingual files) for each of the localizations available for Leopard. These older glossaries can be found here: https://developer.apple.com/internationalization/downloads/ or on the free download section of developer.apsic.com.  This is a valuable reference for anyone localizing applications for the Mac OS platform, so that they are consistent with the terminology in the platform.

Since Leopard, more languages were added to Mac OS, and obviously more UI changes and additions have take place.

Is Apple providing newer glossaries (Lion level) to the development community via is $99 Mac OS Developer program or some other channel?

Comment: Perhaps this would be better asked under SuperUser or Ask Different.

Comment: I thought that perhaps developers would know because Microsoft provides its updated software glossaries via MSDN and perhaps Apple did the same through its developer program, but I can try as well in Ask Different.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer to own question: Just noticed that Apple released on August 6, 2012 the glossaries for Mountain Lion, which can be downloaded from https://developer.apple.com/downloads